# Twitter-like UITableView design

Tags: ios, twitter, uitableview, quartz-core

I'm trying to reproduce the design of Twitter UITableView (see image below) :

[image]

Did not manage to reproduce it :(

I tried several methods like :

- UITableViewController with self.view.layer.borderWidth = 3.0f + shadows + cornerRadius
- UITableViewController with Grouped style and corner Radius
- UIView with UITableView as a subview and corner radius

Any clue to solve my problem please ?

In advance, thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my opinion, this seems to be NOT your classic grouped style UITableView.

This could be a UITableView (plain style) that spans across the whole device width, and composed by custom UITableViewCell's. The cells are narrow enough to leave room for the scroll indicators to be shown.

Each UITableViewCell renders a UIImage on the cell's background: each different, depending on position - top, middle, bottom - or content type. The image for the cell background would already contain the shadow pixels. In an experience of mine, using Quartz for shadow, is too processor intensive and slow, iphone 4). In addition, each custom cell could also have its view setOpaque:TRUE for enhanced performance (against the solid colored background).

Each tweet cell may span different lines/heights so you'd probably use [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tile.png"]] when setting the background of the cell.

So we end up with no real shadow / processor intensive stuff. Just graphics, color matching and positioning.

Comment: Yep, i tried this kind of solution and it works great ! But I though it was possible to do it programmatically :)

Answer (score 2):

This very similar to twitter UI

https://github.com/vicpenap/PrettyKit

Answer (score 0):

I have used a simple trick wherein you use a UIView "Vbg" under UITableView and set the colour of cells and Table to clearcolor. Then increase the height:

```
 Vbg.heightConstraint.constant = number of cells * height of cell.
```

I had to use this for fixed height cells , so this trick came up my mind and it worked pretty well.